# Create ActiveX labels in a loop

Tags: vba, controls, label, activex

I am trying to automate the creation of labels via VBA.

The code runs into

> Run time error 91 - Object variable or With block variable not set

I would like the code to run from label1 (already created in Word), to label24. 
These labels are in Word, and get the data from Excel.

Without the loop section the code runs normally, so the problem is in line

`UserForm1.Controls("Label" & i).Caption =`

When exchanged to the below code, the macro runs normally:

`ThisDocument.Label1.Caption =`

I am doing this in module section

```
Sub CreateLabels()

Dim exWb As Object
Set exWb = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
exWb.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\xxxx")

Dim i As Integer
Dim UserForm1 As Object

For i = 1 To 24

    If exWb.Sheets("Final").Range("I2").Value = _
      "" And exWb.Sheets("Final").Range("F2").Value = "" Then
    'do not put I2 and F2 values if they are missing
    ' (as it creates blank row in the label)

        UserForm1.Controls("Label" & i).Caption = _
          exWb.Sheets("Final").Cells(2, 7) & vbCrLf & _
          exWb.Sheets("Final").Cells(2, 8) & vbCrLf & _
          exWb.Sheets("Final").Cells(2, 10) & vbCrLf & _
          exWb.Sheets("Final").Cells(2, 11)

    ElseIf exWb.Sheets("Final").Range("I2").Value = "" Then

        UserForm1.Controls("Label" & i).Caption = _
          exWb.Sheets("Final").Cells(2, 7) & vbCrLf & _
          exWb.Sheets("Final").Cells(2, 6) & vbCrLf & _
          exWb.Sheets("Final").Cells(2, 8) & vbCrLf & _
          exWb.Sheets("Final").Cells(2, 10) & vbCrLf & _
          exWb.Sheets("Final").Cells(2, 11)

    ElseIf exWb.Sheets("Final").Range("F2").Value = "" Then

        UserForm1.Controls("Label" & i).Caption = _
          exWb.Sheets("Final").Cells(2, 7) & vbCrLf & _
          exWb.Sheets("Final").Cells(2, 8) & vbCrLf & _
          exWb.Sheets("Final").Cells(2, 9) & vbCrLf & _
          exWb.Sheets("Final").Cells(2, 10) & vbCrLf & _
          exWb.Sheets("Final").Cells(2, 11)

    Else:   UserForm1.Controls("Label" & i).Caption = _
          exWb.Sheets("Final").Cells(2, 7) & vbCrLf & _
          exWb.Sheets("Final").Cells(2, 6) & vbCrLf & _
          exWb.Sheets("Final").Cells(2, 8) & vbCrLf & _
          exWb.Sheets("Final").Cells(2, 9) & vbCrLf & _
          exWb.Sheets("Final").Cells(2, 10) & vbCrLf & _
          exWb.Sheets("Final").Cells(2, 11)

    End If

Next i

Set exWb = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Not a solution to you problem, but you really shouldn't be using the default instance of the Userform. There is a good explanation available here: https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/

Comment: Also, what is the value of i when the code fails? just because it works with `Label1` doesn't mean there are all labels from 1 to 24 available.

Comment: A better approach would be to actually name the Labels properly, even if the initial work is higher it pays out in the end. I often use a function in a public module to map Excel cells/labeled rows to certains values/names, this way it is easy to extend the list and identify errors quickly.

Comment: If the ActiveX Parts are on the page itself, check how you can get a collection of the activeX Elements on the Page. .InlineShapes may be the way to go.

Comment: value of i = 1, thus it should be properly working, as it produces Label1 - which is the label name of - as you said - activex label on the word document page. I've just tried it with .inlineshapes, but i do not see any property how to insert the text there.

Comment: ActiveDocument.InlineShapes("Label" & i).Line = I just need the proper property

Comment: Your question is very unclear. It mentions `ThisDocument`, which would be Word. The code in the question is only about `Excel` and a `UserForm`. But no where does it say what the `UserForm` actually *is*. ***Where***, exactly, are these label controls?

Comment: Cindy - when I use "ThisDocument.Label1.Caption =" it connects to excel file and downloads cells into label from it. I have created activeX label on the word document, and I've found solution to use the UserForm, which is, as I suppose, working only if you somehow make the UserForm in vba

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a variable `UserForm1` but don't instantiate it. This variable will prevent the VBA runtime to create the *default instance*. Remove this declaration should fix this.

However, you should consider to read the rubberduck-article *L8n* mentioned in the comments and refactor the code so you don't rely on the default instance. Maybe create the form object and pass it as parameter to your subroutine.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however as I am newbie to VBA i do not know how to "create the form object and pass it as parameter to your subroutine". I have created the labels as an activeX parts on the document itself, I did not create it as a UserForm in vba - as I suppose is the correct method, but I do not know how to tranpose them from the vba to the document

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved by using field:

`Dim fld As Field
For Each fld In ThisDocument.Fields
If exWb.Sheets("Final").Range("I2").Value = "" And exWb.Sheets("Final").Range("F2").Value = "" Then
'do not put I2 and F2 values if they are missing (as it creates blank row in the label)
        fld.OLEFormat.Object.Caption = exWb.Sheets("Final").Cells(q, 7) & vbCrLf 
        & exWb.Sheets("Final").Cells(q, 8) _
        & vbCrLf & exWb.Sheets("Final").Cells(q, 10) & vbCrLf & 
        exWb.Sheets("Final").Cells(q, 11)`